# How do I configure Python to use the same proxy settings of my computer

Tags: python, proxy, configuration

I am tired of configuring proxy settings for all my Python scripts, specially because my work computer is configured with a PAC file.

Can I turn on some "Use system proxy" in Python and forget that proxies exist?

Answer (score 0):

If you use the requests module, then you can set environment variables in your .bashrc or .profile files and they'll get used automatically. Or you can use PyPAC module to make use of the .pac file

```
export HTTP_PROXY="http://10.10.1.10:3128"
export HTTPS_PROXY="http://10.10.1.10:1080"
```

Comment: Sometimes I use requests, sometimes I don't. Also, remember that I'm using a PAC file, so it's not just a matter of configuring one server:port. Can't I just configure Python to use proxy system settings as I do with almost all the other programs in my computer?

Comment: I know you said sometimes you don't use requests, but if you do then PyPAC maybe the way to go because it'll create the session and automatically deal with pac file discovery for you